# Normally distributed and uncorrelated does not imply independent wiki page

Tags: normal-distribution, independence, correlation

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent, it states

> To say that the pair $(X,Y)$ of random variables has a bivariate normal distribution means that every linear combination $aX+bY$ of $X$ and $Y$ for constant (i.e. not random) coefficients $a$ and $b$ has a univariate normal distribution. In that case, if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated then they are independent.[1] However, it is possible for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ **to be so distributed jointly** that each one alone is marginally normally distributed, and they are uncorrelated, but they are not independent; examples are given below.

What does the "to be SO distributed jointly" part mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a grammatical error on Wikipedia. It should read (in my opinion):

> However, it is possible for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ to be jointly distributed and such  that each one alone is marginally normally distributed, and they are uncorrelated, but they are not independent; examples are given below.

The statement is trying to say that if $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same probability space, so that they have a joint distribution, $\mathrm{corr}(X,Y) = 0$ does not imply $X,Y$ are independent.

This is important because of a subtle technicality with normally distributed random variables. If $(X,Y)$ is normally distributed (that is "$X$ and $Y$ are jointly normally distributed") then  $\mathrm{corr}(X,Y) = 0$ implies $X,Y$ are independent. However, if $X$ and $Y$ are both normally distributed, it is actually possible that $(X,Y)$ is *not* normally distributed, in which case $\mathrm{corr}(X,Y) = 0$ does *not* imply that $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: In the quote, when it says "$X$ and $Y$ to be jointly distributed," it's referring to *any* joint distribution, and not specifically the bivariate normal distribution right? That was one of my confusions.

Comment: As for your example, if $X$ and $Y$ are both normally distributed, then $(X,Y)$ will have to be bivariate normal unless $X$ and $Y$ are correlated right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. There are *many* joint distributions of $X,Y$ where $X,Y$ are normal that are not the multivariate normal distribution of the correct dimension, mean, and covariance.

Comment: As for my example, no! If $X,Y$ are both normally distributed, it is still possible that $(X,Y)$ is not bivariate normal even if $X,Y$ are uncorrelated.

Comment: Oh I see. What if we impose the stronger condition of *independence* (as opposed to uncorrelated) between $X$ and $Y$. Then in that case any linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ will be a normally distributed random variable, hence their joint distribution must be bibariate?

Comment: Indeed, if the stronger assumption that $X,Y$ are independent is used, then $(X,Y)$ will be bivariate normal, which you can check by multiplying their densities. In that case, any linear combination of $X,Y$ will be a univariate normal.

Comment: The more general theorem here is that if $Z$ is an $n$-dimensional multivariate normal, and $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear, then $L(Z)$ is an $m$-dimensional multivariate normal (possibly degenerate covariance matrix).